# Prove that if $P(B|A) > P(B)$ then $P(B^C | A) < P(B^C)$

Tags: probability

Is this a correct proof? Assume probabilities are all non zero.
$$P(B|A) > P(B)$$
$$P(B|A) - 1 > P(B) - 1$$
multiplying both sides by -1 we get 
$$1 - P(B|A) < 1 - P(B)$$
which is equivalent to
$$P(B^C|A) < P(B^C)$$

Comment: looks like it..

Comment: Indeed.  Which part is causing doubt?

Comment: Interpreting the result. I feel like all i did was move blocks of stuff around however i have no intuition as to wether or not this conclusion is true

Comment: You can interpret this as: Suppose that event $B$ is more likely to occur when we know that event $A$ occurs, then, given event $A$, $B$ not occuring is less likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

Intuition : If the fact that A is true increases your belief that B is true, then it also decreases your belief that non B is true (that is exactly the opposite :-) )